# Application with rhomobile and jQuery mobile is slow

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, mobile, rhomobile

I've developed a mobile application with rhomobile + jQuery Mobile.

When I deploy it on a mobile phone "for android", it is very slow.

Could you help me to find the reason?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what exactly is acting "very slow"? Is it transitions, scrolling down a long list, loading pages? It will help us suggest a solution if we know where the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deactivate transition in your Rhodes app very easily to give it a try.
In the layout.erb file inside the app folder of your Rhodes application, you can find:

```
// Uncomment these options in case of performance problem in pages transition
//$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
//$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
//$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
//$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
//$.mobile.loadingMessageDelay = 50; // in ms
```

Just uncomment it and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what wrapper is used (Rhomobile/Phonegap) jQuery mobile will have extremely bad performances on android devices (mainly 2.X, but sam thing relates to 4+ versions).

On the devices that have this problem (mostly Android) there isn't anything you can do. It is a browser limitation. Android mobile browsers are notorious for poor transitions.

On iOS, you have to be aware of a couple of issues. First of all, Webviews are hampered by slower Javascript than Mobile Safari, because they lack the Just-in-time compile feature. It's not Rhodes-specific. The same Javascript will run slower in a Webview than it will in Mobile Safari itself, and there is no getting around it.

Secondly, iOS does not automatically use hardware acceleration for transitions. You can "hint" the browser to use hardware acceleration by using a null 3D transform, like translateZ(0). Search for more information on this. There is a bit of an art to picking the right elements to do this on, since it can be costly to apply this to a large number of elements, and it usually isn't necessary to apply it to the entire element heirarchy.

My best advice, though, is to not use transitions, because they aren't handled well yet on a wide variety of mobile devices. IMO, no transition is a vastly superior user experience anyway. Transitions are used mainly to distract the user from slow software, ironically introducing more delay in the process.